# How can I pass a ViewModel property to an ajax post method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

```
 function ResendEmailInvite(internalUserId, familyMemberId) { 
       theinternalUserId = internalUserId;
       theFamilyMemberId = familyMemberId;
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to resend this family member's invite?')){
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:"/Admin/ResendFamilyMemberEmail",
             data: {internalUserId : theinternalUserId, familyMemberId : theFamilyMemberId}, 
             success: function(response){
                alert(response);
             },
             error: function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am  using ASP.net MVC 3.
This is an **ajax/javascript** method in my view.

As far as the syntax goes, is this correct?

The `familyMemberId` is going to be dynamic, however, the `userId` is not.
I want to pass the `userId` from my viewModel to this ajax call, how can I do this?

Comment: have you tried replacing `theinternalUserId` with `@userId`?

Comment: so just take the viewmodel property and tack on the @ symbol at the front?  The internal user id is actually a property of a User object which is inside the viewModel. so it would be InternalUser.UserId to access it...  how would it go then?

Comment: Actually, in your controller, you need to pass it to the `ViewBag`.  `ViewBag.userId = userId`. Then do `internalUserId:@ViewBag.userId` in the appropriate place in your javascript.

Comment: what if i don't want to use a viewbag?  I mean i will if i have to, but is there another option?

Comment: The standard method is to create a custom class to pass to the View(), but I haven't researched that yet. Try the [MSDN library](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views).

Comment: @user1977591 You can mix Razor and JavaScript commands, there's no problem. Simply add `@Model.familyMemberId` to your javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is get the data from the model in your controller into the view. This is what MVC is all about. From the [MSDN MVC 4 Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4):

### Controller:

You can define your model using the VS menu system and the Entity Framework so you're actually accessing the database.

```
 public class YourController : Controller
{
     private YourDBContext db = new YourDBContext();

     public ActionResult YourAction(int user_id = 0)
    {
        User user = db.Users.find(user_id);
        if(user == null) {
           return HttpNotFound(); // Or unauthorized or whatever
        }
        return View(user);
    }
    //...
```

### View:

```
@Model IEnumerable<MvcUser.Models.User>

<!-- other stuff -->

 <script type="text/javascript>
 // the rest of your script
        function ResendEmailInvite(internalUserId, familyMemberId) { 
           theinternalUserId = @Model.userId;
           theFamilyMemberId = familyMemberId;
          if(confirm('Are you sure you want to resend this family member's invite?')){
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url:"/Admin/ResendFamilyMemberEmail",
                 data: {internalUserId : theinternalUserId, familyMemberId : theFamilyMemberId}, 
                 success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                 },
                 error: function(){
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This works because, as you pointed out, the userId is not dynamic after the page has loaded. You would need to create some other hook in your HTML for javascript to grab if you wanted really dynamic behavior.